# How do i disable microphone automatic correction?

Tags: sound, skype

I have one nasty problem. When i use skype, my mic corrects himself alone. Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean when you say that your "mic corrects ..."?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Skype's option menu, then to audio devices and there you can untick the automatic mic correction.